# How to write to both GPT and MBR manually?

Tags: boot, mbr, gpt

I have a big deal here. I have a MacBook with three partitions:

1. HFS partition for Mac OS X 10.6
2. NTFS partition for  Windows 7 64-Bit
3. NTFS partition for my documents

It thus works with both GPT and MBR. I use [rEFIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REFIt) to switch the system at boot.

Having had troubles with my Windows roaming increasing dramatically (what a pain), I had to increase the size of my second partition after reducing my third partition...

My problem is that my partitioning tool did a mess with the GPT and the MBR (I am a beginner to these systems and I used EaseUS's tool to work on the partitions. It was a big mistake.)

Now I have the following.

#### In the GPT

```
Partition  Start LBA     End LBA Type

1                 40      409639 EFI System (FAT)     ⇐ The boot sector, I guess
                                                      ⇐ I miss my Mac OS partition (the entry was suppressed by Easeus)
2          126240768   252067839 Basic Data           ⇐ My Windows partition
3          278693928   976773165 Basic Data           ⇐ My Documents partition at the right place
```

#### In the MBR

```
Partition   Start LBA    End LBA Type

1                   1     409639 EE               ⇐ The boot sector I guess
2              409640  125976615 AF Mac OS X HFS+ ⇐ My Mac OS partition at the right place etc
2           126240768  252067839 07 NTFS/HPFS     ⇐ my Windows partition
3           252069888  976773165 07 NTFS/HPFS     ⇐ my Documents partition at the WRONG old place
```

rEFIt offers me to automatically copy the content of my GPT to my MBR: It would give me back access to my "documents" partition, but I would lose my OS X partition.

How do I manually write in those GPT and MBR to setup both sides? I heard it would be possible with UBCD …

Comment: **Neither** of those are the boot sector.  The EFI System Partition is your [system volume](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html) and the type `EE` entry in the old-style partition table is a protective placeholder.

Comment: OK, thanks for the TIP. But could you tell me how to write those two tables ?

Comment: I was going to, but was beaten by Rod Smith I see.  I personally recover from such situations with a hex editor.  But my recommendation to you would have been the same as M. Smith's: Re-add the partition to the EFI table using a non-destructive create and then update the old-style table from the EFI one.  I also agree with M. Smith on the avoidance of hybrid partitioning unless one knows fully what one is doing.  Why don't you just get your 64-bit Windows 7 to use the EFI partition table directly [as it can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463525#X-201104111922342)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your advices.

I followed them and got help from Rod Smith (creater of gdisk).

The problem came from the fact that Easeus (the partition tool I used) was not aware of "hybrid MBR/GPT" systems. It did a mess thus.

Here were the steps to be taken : 
1) using gdisk I repaired the GPT : 
- added the missing Mac partition (command 'n' in gdisk stating the type AF and the begin and end position)
- sorted the partitions for it to become the second one as expected (command 's' in gdisk)
2) I have recreated the hybrid MBR based on these data ('x' command and then 'h' command in gdisk).

Of course, Gdisk allows also to create a backup of both partitions tables. That is a great tool and Rod's documentation on his website rodsbooks.com is great too (with examples and so on).

If you have a dual boot Mac with Windows that is great to correct your messed up partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Its Live CD includes the package [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) (GPT fdisk) which can repair GPT/MBR inconsistencies. It might be enough for your needs.

I suggest that you first read very carefully the tutorial, and especially the section [Repairing GPT Disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html).

Comment: I have burnt the gparted live CD, but when booting on it. It stops with no reason in the middle of the process... No way to have it continue.

Comment: Does this [thread](http://forums.techguy.org/linux-unix/875584-solved-cannot-boot-gparted-live.html) help ? If not, does it stop with any message (or what is the last displayed message) ?

Comment: No actually my problem is not solved... sadly. Rod Smith (the editor of gparted gave me good advices but I can't actually solve my issue...

Best regards.

Comment: The above thread also gave such advice as using a Linux distribution that contains gdisk. The list is [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/download.html#emergency). You might try a LiveCD, for example [Fedora LiveCD](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD) is one of the best at detecting hardware.